# JLS8. Generic class declaration definition

Tags: java, generics, jls

Sorry if my question isn't new but i can't find it.

Now i'm reading jls8 and i can't understand one definition from it. In chapter **[8.1.5 Superinterfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5)** i encounter with this

*Given a generic class declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0), the direct superinterfaces of
the parameterized class type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is a type, are all types
`I<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>`, where `I<U1,...,Uk>` is a direct superinterface of `C<F1,...,Fn>` and θ is
the substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].*

If i correctly understand, this definition means that i can assign `List<String> = ArrayList<String>` but not e.g. `List<String> = ArrayList<Integer>`.But i'm not sure. Can someone explain this with more details and examples. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you quoted is a statement about *superinterfaces*, not a statement about what you can assign to what.

In the context of `List<String>`, and `ArrayList<String>`, the statement says that `List<String>` is a direct superinterface of `ArrayList<String>`. It says nothing about whether you can or cannot assign one to the other.

The specification specifies whether you can assign a value to a variable in section [5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2). In it, it says that a widening reference conversion, which is further specified in section [5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5), is allowed. We see that a widening conversion is allowed from `S` to `T` if `S` is a subtype of `T`.

And from section [4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10), we can see a lot of rules about what counts as a subtype. Eventually you'll find a bunch of rules that when applied together, implies that `T` is a direct superinterface of `S`, then `S` is a subtype of `T`.